# Is the Field Norm Distributive over Multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let the field norm $N_{L/K}$ for a field extension $L/K$ be given by (for $\alpha\in L$)

$N_{L/K}(\alpha)=(\prod_{j=1}^n \sigma_j(\alpha))^{[L:K(\alpha)]}$,

where $\sigma_j(\alpha)$ are the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $K$. If $L/K$ is a Galois extension, then

$N_{L/K}(\alpha)=\prod_{\sigma\in Gal(L/K)} \sigma(\alpha)$,

which is distributive over multiplication in $L$ because the automorphisms $\sigma$ are. In particular:

$N_{L/K}(\alpha\beta)=\prod_{\sigma\in Gal(L/K)} \sigma(\alpha\beta)=\prod_{\sigma\in Gal(L/K)} \sigma(\alpha)\prod_{\sigma\in Gal(L/K)}\sigma(\beta)=N_{L/K}(\alpha)N_{L/K}(\beta)$.

**Question:** For an arbitrary field extension $L/K$, is the norm $N_{L/k}$ distributive over multiplication?

Comment: Sure, $N_{L/K}$ is multiplicative, this is because $N_{L/K}(\alpha) = \det( x\to \alpha x\in End_K(L))$

Comment: The way you define $N_{L/K}$ it would not be multiplicative in inseparable extensions because there is something missing in the exponent (inseparable degree)